# Call a program inside a .cs file from a javascript function for onkeypress function ASP.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, events, onkeypress

I am trying to create a textbox which updates the text in it after a key has been pressed, so I have created a program inside the class of the page which executes the function I want. The program works fine, my question is how do I call that program in the javascript function when onkeypress event happens:

//My text box:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyBox" onkeypress="AutoText(); return false;" runat="server" 
      Width="400px" ToolTip="Text?" CausesValidation="True" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:TextBox>
```

//My function

```
function AutoText() 
{
    var i;
    i = Class1.BoxTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e);
}
```

I know the function doesn't work and that's not how to call a program from a c# class in JavaScript, I am only asking if it's possible how to do it.

Note that I did research this as much as I can, maybe the searches I did were of no use because there are so many subjects to this topic or maybe I just did it wrong :P

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing client and server side. ASP.NET is executed from server side, and Javascript is executed from client side.

So, you cannot call an ASP.NET function directly from Javascript in your case, because the server cannot access to the client side textbox.

Your solution is to write this function in Javascript. It could be something like that :

```
function boxTextChanged(text) {
    getElementById('textBoxToUpdate').value(text);
}
```

By the way, I just want to add that you *can* call ASP.NET directly in Javascript using **ajax**, but server side will never be able to update directly DOM on the client side. Usually, ajax is used to get datas from server.

Comment: Thanks this is quite helpful, however my main problem is importing the text string from the C# program in the class, to the js function how do i do that?

Comment: @user3378869 To be clear, you want when the user inputs some text in the textbox, it should be written on another textbox/div or whatever ?

Comment: That part matter less, but anyhow it should replace the text in the same box, again the problem for me is getting the text the the program in the class edited imported to the js function in order to execute what Nathan said. :)

Comment: @user3378869 you can pass the value from your ASP.NET to your Javascript using `var jsVariable = @yourASPVariableName` if it is a string

Comment: Really? that's exactly what I'll use thanks a bunch!

Comment: function AutoText() {
    var QueryTextCorrected = @QueryCorrection;
        OrderQueryBox.Text = QueryTextCorrected;
      }

Comment: @user3378869 This is almost it, but to access to your `OderQueryBox.Text` you have to use the syntax I showed you in my answer, giving the textbox an id.

Comment: function AutoText() {
    var QueryTextCorrected = @InvisibleTextLabel.Text;
        OrderQueryBox.Text = QueryTextCorrected;
      }

Comment: I have added an invisible label to store the text from the program and then get it to the js function but the onkeypress doesn't seem to respond at all

Comment: Well now I've realized this js function beats the entire point of onkeypress event as far as the .cs program is concerned... I'm at a loss... I just want to call the program every time there is a keystroke...

Comment: @user3378869 You are doing it wrong. Take a look at my answer and change `OrderQueryBox.Text` according to what I showed to you using `getElementById` and giving your textbox an Id.

Comment: more like this?

            function AutoText() {
    var QueryTextCorrected = @InvisibleTextLabel.Text;
        getElementById('OrderQueryBox').value(QueryTextCorrected);
      }

Comment: <script>
        var QueryTextCorrected = @QueryCorrection;
    function AutoText() {
        getElementById('OrderQueryBox').value(QueryTextCorrected);
      }
      </script>

Comment: @user3378869 last one should work. Did you gave your text box an Id ? Any errors in the console? Oops, my bad it is `document.getElementById`

Comment: oh thanks for the document. and yeah it has an idea and the thing is there were no errors to start with. Anyhow thanks I'll tinker from here on out :)

Comment: @user3378869 Pleased to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can call the web method onkeypress envt and pass it the value of text box which will update the database with text box value.
which is done by javascript so that you did not required post back of whole page so it improve your performance.